# EditLive! Rich Text Editor - submitting form via ajax

Tags: ajax

The project I'm working on is using the Java EditLive! rich text editor.  I've been trying to make the EditLive form post via ajax, but am having some problems using IE8.  Here are the steps we're taking:

1. Load the main page
2. The user clicks a link and the EditLive applet is loaded and attached to the page via ajax
3. The user finishing editing their document and clicks the submit button
4. The form posts via ajax (we're using jQuery.post())
5. The EditLive section is reloaded and the EditLive content is correct.
6. The form immediately posts again
7. The EditLive content is back to being blank.

Unfortunately (for debugging reasons), this is not happening in FireFox - there is only a single form post and the values are saved correctly.

From what I can tell debugging this in IE8, it looks like the submit event is getting called twice with 2 different forms.  My thought is that the applet isn't getting destroyed correctly, though I've tried everything in my power to destroy it.

So I was wondering if anyone has any experience successfully submitting EditLive data via ajax?  Or maybe this is just a limitation to the product?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue but you likely want to look at the autoSubmit property of EL:

- http://docs.ephox.com/display/EditLive7/AutoSubmit+Property
- http://docs.ephox.com/display/EditLive/AutoSubmit+Property

I suspect that by using an AJAXy submit process this is somehow causing you issues with EditLive and its standard behavior.  I would try turning off autoSubmit and grabbing the content yourself in your jQuery posting process.